# Create a Response in Cache with Response-Type "cors"

Tags: javascript, cors, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, cachestorage

I am having a problem updating a Cache in Cache Storage to reflect our changes when the application is offline as I cannot create a Response object with a type of "cors" with is the one that was cache when the application was online.

I needed to update a previous cache response with a `Response-Type: cors` as the application looks for this Request-Response pair with similar properties when it tries to fetch a `GET` request again when offline.

I tried updating it by using `cache.put(req, res)`. However, I cannot procedurally create a [Response object with a Response-Type of "cors"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response) as it only creates "default" unless by an actual network call which it seems to produce one.

Any way I can craft a Response object with a `Response-Type: cors` or update an existing cache body?

I tried to `extends` the Response object to enable modifying the `Response-Type`

Here's the code that updates the cache:

```
// Extend Response to use Response-Type cors
class CacheResponse extends Response {
    type = "cors";
    url = "https://localhost:5001/api/Customer?id=e2b9b098-2fd8-423b-8928-e234d80d39ed";
}

// PUT the cache
caches.open("ngsw:1:data:dynamic:api-customer:cache").then((cache) => {

    let req = new Request("https://localhost:5001/api/Customer?id=e2b9b098-2fd8-423b-8928-e234d80d39ed", {
        method: "GET",
        mode: undefined,
        headers: {
            'Accept': "application/json",
            'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36",
            'Origin': 'https://localhost:9001',
            'Referer': 'https://localhost:9001/app/customers/e2b9b098-2fd8-423b-8928-e234d80d39ed'
        }
    })

    let res = new CacheResponse(
        JSON.stringify({
            "id": "e2b9b098-2fd8-423b-8928-e234d80d39ed",
            "name": "Alvin Long",
        }), {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Date': 'Fri, 05 Jul 2019 14:47:27 GMT',
                'Server': 'Kestrel',
                'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
            },
            type: "cors"
        });

    cache.put(req, res)
});
```

This creates another cache with the same property as the previous one aside from the `Response-Type`

Comment: Why do you want to create a response with type `"cors"`? They have less visibility than a response with a `"default"` type.

Comment: The first network call has a type of `"cors"` when I tried to cache.put another one in the cache and make a request again offline it doesn't cache.match from that and returns a 404, I forgot to mention that the one that takes care of the cache.match is ngsw datagroups.

Comment: The mode of the request is not involved in matching the request via `cache.match`. Does your response have a `Vary` header?

Comment: @JaffaTheCake Thanks for your comment... I had the exact same problem @jbalintac had posted about and assumed the `Response-Type: cors` thing was the difference.  Turns out I had different hostnames and just didn't see it because it wasn't shown in the dev tools.  :-)  Your comment helped me see forest-through-trees so thanks for that!